# Two solutions with the same settings show different behavior in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have two different solutions in VS2015, and both of them have the box `For new solutions use the currently selected project as the startup project` ticked in `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run`.

But just one of the solutions allows me to change a new project to run, by clicking on the project, or on any of its dependencies. For the other solution I have to click the project with the right-mouse button and choose `Set as startup project`.

What exactly is making the two solutions to have such distinct behaviors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a setting of the Solution.

Right click your solution

`Properties -> Common Properties -> Startup Project -> Current Selection`

The *Current Selection* option is a radio button with *Single startup project* and *Multiple startup projects* being your other 2 options

[image]

The `CheckBox` asked about

`Tools -> Options... -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run`

[image]

Is used to set the setting described previously by default for any new Visual Studio solution that is created

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great answer. I was not aware of this option. But then, what is the purpose of the alluded box in `Tools`?

Comment: @ChairmanMao No problem. Not sure I know what you mean by alluded box

Comment: The box that is ticked in `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run` which I referred to in my question.

Comment: @ChairmanMao The checkbox you describe is used to set the setting that my answer describes by default when a new solution is created so that you do not have to set the solution setting every time you create a new solution. I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: It makes sense because the first time I used such a box, it worked. But I couldn't make it work in a new solution I've just started in VS2015. Thanks.